# Which weak topology is this?

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology, calculus-of-variations, weak-topology

I read this definition in a book about variational inequalities of Kinderlehrer and Stampacchia.

The concept of mapping continuous on finite dimensional subspaces is introduced in [Definition III.1.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=_-SHWxrHCToC&pg=PA84).

> **Definition 1.2.** The mapping $A$ from $\mathbb K\to X'$ is *continuous on finite dimensional subspaces* if for any finite dimensional subspace $M$ a $X$ the restriction of $A$ to $\mathbb K\cap M$ is weakly continuous, namely, if
>   $$A \colon \mathbb K\cap M \to X'$$
>   is weakly continuous.

The concept of weak continuity is mentioned in the definition, but I don't think it is related to the usual weak topology defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology).

Thank you very much for any hints.

Comment: I have tried to retype the text from your picture. (So if you're satisfied with the result, you can remove the picture.) BTW adding one of already existing tags would probably better than only creating new tags.(Since new tags have no followers. One of the followers of tag you use might notice the question.) I think that some of the tags ([tag:functional-analysis]), ([tag:calculus-of-variations]), ([tag:terminology]) might be suitable here.

Comment: We also need, from the previious page, $X$ is a Banach space with dual $X'$,  and $\mathbb K \subset X$ is a closed convex set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors mean the weak* topology on $X'$, i.e., the topology induced by the family of seminorms $p_x(x^*) = |\langle x^*, x\rangle|$, $x\in X$. So, for every  finite dimensional space $M$ the map $K\cap M\to X'$ must be continuous with respect to the standard topology on $M$, restricted to $K\cap M$, and the weak* topology on $X'$.

Another way to express the above: for every $x\in X$, the scalar function $z\mapsto \langle Az, x\rangle$  is continuous on $K\cap M$. You can see this fact being used on page 85, soon after the definition.

Comment: Thank you so much. In conclusion, $X$ and $X^\prime$ are equiped the weak topology and weak*-topology, respectively.